# Piping stdio to file AND to parent process

Tags: node.js

I would like to stream the stdout/stderr of a child process to both a file and to the parent process.

Say I have this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const fd = fs.openSync('bar.log','a');

const child = cp.spawn('node', [ 'foo.js' ], {
  cwd: __dirname,
  stdio: [ 'ignore', fd, fd ]
});

// using stdio array above I send stdout/stderr to log file
// but I would still like to receive stdout/stderr to this process so I can do something else with it

child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

child.stdout.on('data', function (d) {
  console.log('stdout => ', d);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (d) {
  console.log('stderr => ', d);
});
```

If you run this, it will give me this error:

```
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEncoding' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/private/exp9.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (node.js:348:7)
    at startup (node.js:140:9)
    at node.js:463:3
```

What it's saying is that by not choosing 'pipe' for stdout or stderr, that stdout/stderr of the child will not be piped to the parent process. And accordingly child.stdout and child.stderr are not defined...

But what if I want to pipe stdout/stderr to both the parent and to the file?

Do I have to do this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const child = cp.spawn('node', [ 'foo.js' ], {
  cwd: __dirname,
  stdio: [ 'ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe' ]
});

// using stdio array above I send stdout/stderr to log file
// but I would still like to receive stdout/stderr to this process so I can do something else with it

child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

const strm = fs.createWriteStream('bar.log');

child.stdout.pipe(strm);   //new code
child.stderr.pipe(strm);   //new code

child.stdout.on('data', function (d) {
  console.log('stdout => ', d);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (d) {
  console.log('stderr => ', d);
});
```

Or perhaps there is another way of doing this that I haven't seen?

Comment: Piping to the file and listening to data is the way to go. Anyway, probably there are multiple ways of doing this, but yours is effective and performance-optimised.